# php include path on windows

Tags: php, path, include

I work with PHP on Windows, sience a few days. The whole time I've been indicated include in the following manner:

In index.php file:

```
require ('include/init.inc');
```

In the directory "include" I stated:

In init.inc file:

```
require ("workbench.inc");
```

But suddenly no longer works. At one time I must also in "init.inc" specify the directory. 
Why did it all the time to work, and suddenly no more?

Comment: You have to be a bit more explicit. Are you using PHP with Apache or on CLI? What is your directory structure?

Comment: I work with Eclipse and use XDebug. The Application is configured and it's runnig as an CLI Application, but I have installed wamp also and the wamp Server is still running. The dir stucture is very simple. I have a root and an include dir.

Comment: When I put the code into "include/init.inc": set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'D:\...my path ...\include'); then it works fine. But until todayit was not necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation:](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing

So the [current working directory](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) (CWD) is important when including other files. It can be retrieved by `getcwd()`.

If your directory structure looks like this

```
rootdir/
    include/
        init.rc
        workbench.rc
    index.php
```

then a `require('include/init.rc')` will only work if `rootdir/` is the CWD or is part of the search path. Likewise, `require('init.inc')` assumes the CWD is `rootdir/include/`. Since the current working directory can change, it is idomatic in PHP to use the more robust

```
// in index.php
require(__DIR__ . '/include/init.rc');

// in workbench.rc
require(__DIR__ . '/init.rc');
```

Then the `require` will work independent of the CWD. This works because the [magic constant `__DIR__`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is replaced by the absolute path to the file that contains the constant without a trailing directory separator, for example

- in `index.php`, `__DIR__` is `D:\path\to\rootdir` and
- in `include/init.rc`, `__DIR__` is `D:\path\to\rootdir\include`.